# From a pandas column of lists, how to remove all values not in another column of list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a two list columns in a dataframe. One column have unique list elements and another column have duplicate list elements. How can i compare two columns and exact occurrences of the list elements including duplicates into a new dataframe column.
Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[['1', '2'],['3', '4'],['8','9']],
               'B':[['1', '1', '2'],['3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '5'],['2','2']]})
print(df) 

   A                   B
0  [1, 2]           [1, 1, 2]
1  [3, 4]  [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
2  [8, 9]              [2, 2]
```

Desired Output:

```
    A                   B                C
0  [1, 2]           [1, 1, 2]        [1, 1, 2]
1  [3, 4]  [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]  [3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
2  [8, 9]              [2, 2]               []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us check for loop with `zip`

```
df['C'] = [[z for z in y if z in x ] for x , y in zip(df.A, df.B)]
df
        A                   B                C
0  [1, 2]           [1, 1, 2]        [1, 1, 2]
1  [3, 4]  [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]  [3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
2  [8, 9]              [2, 2]               []
```